# Problems deploying ASP.NET 4 app to Web Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I just created my first ASP.NET Version 4 app using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Express 2008.

I copied the files to IIS and run the default.asp.  This loads the programs main menu.  So far so good.

When I open the read webform and do a read of my database I get the following Error:

### Server Error in '/Diary' Application.

Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at [support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980) articile for the very issue.

Or even [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/fbf32aa8-2125-4919-be81-3baa399e2e0d)